# Bartender 2016 R9 Integration will not print when specifying "Copies" using SQL database as source

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, bartender

I have designed a label using Bartender 2016 R9. All the fields use Embedded Data as the type. It prints to a Zebra thermal printer just fine.

I have setup a Bartender Integration which uses this label and uses an ADO.NET connection to get values from an Azure SQL database. The connection works fine as I can see the data in the Record Browser in Bartender Integration. I have used the "Specify values for named data sources" option and filled in the fields and also set the "Copies" option to the database quantity column.

The issue I have is that when I do a test print, I get the following error:

```
Unable to run action 'Print Document' because the copies per serial number value of '%quantity%' is invalid. Please specify a valid number and re-run the action.
```

If I manually enter a number into the "Copies" field and print it works just fine.

I thought it might a data type issue as the column in the database was set to INT so changed it to VARCHAR, same issue. I also tried manually changing the SQL statement to convert from INT to VARCHAR but I get the same error.

The error mentions serial numbers yet the label is not setup to use them and the option to use serial numbers in the integration is also unchecked. The fact that it will print if I manually enter a number into the Copies field suggests that it has nothing to do with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Which language does your pc/server have?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd ask is are you using the 'ZDesigner' Driver (from the Zebra manufacturers) or the 'Zebra' Print driver from Seagull (from the makers of Bartender) for the printer?  I have found that the Seagull Driver works better with Bartender Software... go figure :)

The seagull drivers actually have different preferences and options on the Printer Properties tabs.

You might also check to see if you have any conditional Print settings in the btw file.  If you look under the document's page setup, on the Templates tab, there is a 'print when' option.

Comment: Hey, it appears to be a glitch with 2016 not converting the variable merge tags with the actual values from the Azure SQL connection. We upgraded to 2021 and with the exact same setup it works as expected converting the variables.